# How and where to add a custom JavaScript function to CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Not sure if I'm asking the right question here as searching the web yielded disappointing results.

I'd like to add a custom and pure JavaScript function for use in several views such as a hash computation or other utility function.

Namely, how and where would I place the `hash` function below to make it available to all my views (with a design document):

```
function(doc) {
  function hash(input) { 
    return (input || 0).toString().length;
  }

  if(doc.username) {
    emit(doc.username, {
      clientId: doc.clientId,
      username: doc.username,
      password: doc.password,
      hash: hash(doc.clientId)
    });
  }
}
```

Obvisouly the example is an oversimplification but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CommonJS Modules](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs-modules) to share code.

In short, you add the raw JS source code to your design document and it can be loaded by any views contained in that design document.

If you're not familiar with how to make or use CommonJS modules, the node.js community uses CommonJS modules extensively, so there is a lot of documentation and examples out there on the syntax.

Comment: but where or how add a module? i've have not found on the web, there is a folder? or a command to add ? I don't see that on fauxton

Comment: The link I added goes to the documentation which shows a low-level example. You can use tools like [couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp) to map a directory to your design document. (including your CommonJS modules)